# MySQLi Query Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

There problem my PHP Script. When I run the script it shows an error:

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

The error is in this line:

```
$result=mysqli_query($selectQuery);
```

My script is below:

```
global $conn;
$prod_cat_names = "'" . str_replace( ",", "','", $values["prod_cat"] ) . "'";

/* Select Query as SELECT from previous example: */
$selectQuery = 
"
    SELECT sup_id, sup_name, sup_prod_name, sup_contactperson, sup_email, ".$values["tender_id"]." 
      FROM view_rfq_suppliersmerge 
     WHERE sup_prod_name IN ( {$prod_cat_names} )
     GROUP BY sup_name
";

/* Perform the query: */
$result=mysqli_query($selectQuery);
//$result = $db->query( $selectQuery );
//$result->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );


$insertQuery = array();

/* Process result and pre-fill Insert Query: */
 while($row=db_fetch_array($result))
{
    $insertQuery[] = "'" . implode( "', '",$row ) . "'";
}

/* Format INSERT Query: */
$insertQuery =
"
INSERT INTO rfq_suppliers 
            (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) 
            VALUES
            ('
            . implode( '), (', $insertQuery )
            ')
";

/* Perform INSERT Query: */
db_exec($insertQuery,$conn);
```

Comment: Add db link as first parameter. You need to provide database link as first parameter. Read manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: did you even read the error message?

Comment: Yes i did, couldnt solve, that's why posted here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link to the database connection to perform a query against the db.

```
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$selectQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add db link as first parameter. Error is self explanatory -

> "mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters"

You need to provide database connection variable as first parameter. [Read manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Based on your code, replace it with this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $selectQuery);
```

Comment: :) yea I added in comments first, then while was working on my answer, looks like you posted it too. See, my comment is the first one posted here.

Comment: :) Thank you Muhammed and gavgrif...:) that problem is solved. A new error arised now. But do i need to put as another question or i can mentioned it here itself.?

Answer (score 0):

The connection variable is the first parameter in `mysqli_query`. Please try this.

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$selectQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah thanx.. Someone guided me and i solved it. Thanx once again

Comment: Not a problem. Happy coding :)